# How far away could zeppelins drop bombs?

Tags: world-war-one, aircraft

I am doing a little World War 1 reading for a class, and I came to this passage:

> German **dirigibles**, or zeppelins, were able to drop bombs on targets that were 700 miles away. This was far beyond the reach of any airplane.

The text also says that zeppelins

> glided across the sky at night, traveling just 25 miles per hour.

I haven't been able to find any information on how far they could bomb from, but I did some research and zeppelin bombers in WW1 were dropping artillery shells. Traveling that slow and dropping shells, I doubt it is possible that the low-flying bombers achieve that.

Is this just a typo, or could German zeppelin bombers really hit targets from 700 miles away?

Comment: I think that the passage means that zeppelins were capable of flying 700 miles, i.e. the targets were 700 miles from their bases. Not that they could hit targets 700 miles from the zeppelin itself.

Comment: The "derigible" is really a "dirigible".

Answer (score 4):

Compared to the aircraft of the day, Zeppelins were very long ranged, high flying, and slow but not excessively so. The payload was impressive, too.

- Top speed was close to 60 mph. Cruise speed was lower.
- Range was well over 700 miles. Some were closer to [7,000 miles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ_104_%28L_59%29).
- Ceiling was up to 20,000 feet.

Fighter aircraft [could and did intercept airships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leefe_Robinson), but that required luck and skill.

Heavier than air aviation had a greater development potential and fewer operational problems, so they overshadowed lighter than air *after* WWI.

Comment: Zeppelin -the company- also produced heavier than air large bombers that were more effective bombers.

Answer (score 3):

[Germany conducted a harrassment campaign against England in World War I using both Zeppelins and airplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_strategic_bombing_during_World_War_I).

Some Zeppelins had ranges in excess of 700 miles and could fly over 24,000 feet high, well beyond the operating ceiling of WWI-era aircraft.